# Image opens on full screen when clicked

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-slick

I am using react-slick to display a list of images.

```
class AppScreenshotsUI extends Component {
  render() {
    var settings = {
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      draggable: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 2.3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false,
      className: 'ad_ss',
    };

    let slides = []
    this.props.appDetail.screenShots.map((src,i) =>
      slides.push(
        <div key={i}>
          <div className='cont'> {/* needed */}
            <img src={src} className='round shadow' alt='' />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    )

    return (
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {slides}
      </Slider>
    );
  }
}

export default AppScreenshotsUI
```

I want to enable an onClick method which opens the image on full screen, when clicked. I tried various react-slick settings but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you want your image to be opened in a new tab ?

Comment: No i want it to open in the same tab.

Comment: You should import a library doing it for you, like react-image-lightbox. You should read about Array.map in the mozilla doc as well. To do React well you need a minimum JS skill.